# Laravel upload dynamic file type input and store to database

Tags: laravel, dynamic

This is the code I'm trying to work with, and I get 'no-image.jpg' in my database field and as I add the second dynamic row in my form when I submit it I get 'Undefined offset: 1'. Everything works fine except file input.

This is part of my form which is dynamic and I can add more rows:

```
                <table id="myTable" class=" table order-list">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{Form::label('Payment', 'پرداخت')}}</td>
                    <td>{{Form::label('PaymentDate', 'تاریخ')}}</td>
                    <td>{{Form::label('Account', 'حساب')}}</td>
                    <td>{{Form::label('Attachment_link', 'تصویر پرداخت')}}</td>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="col-md-2">
                        {{Form::text('pay[]', '', ['class' => 'form-control number', 'placeholder' => ''])}}
                    </td>
                    <td class="col-md-2">
                        {{Form::text('payDate[]', '', ['class' => 'form-control pDate', 'placeholder' => ''])}}
                    </td>
                    <td class="col-md-2">
                        <select name="account[]" class="form-control selectpicker">
                            <option></option>
                            <option>دفتر وکالت</option>
                            <option>دفتر موسسه</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td class="col-md-1">
                        {{Form::file('attachment_link[]')}}
                    </td>
                    <td class="col-md-2"><a class="deleteRow"></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="5" style="text-align: left;">
                        <input type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary" id="addrow" value="اضافه کردن پرداخت جدید" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
```

This is my controller:

```
    $input = $request->all();
    $pays = $request->input('pay');
    $paymentDates = $request->input('payDate');
    $account = $request->input('account');
    $attachment = $request->file('attachment_link');

    for($i=0; $i< count($input['pay']); $i++) {
        if ($request->hasFile($attachment[$i])) {
            $fileNameWithExt = $request->file($attachment[$i])->getClientOriginalName();
            // Get just filename
            $filename = pathinfo($fileNameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            // Get just ext
            $extention = $request->file($attachment[$i])->getClientOriginalExtension();
            // Filename to store
            $fileNameToStore = $filename . '_' . time() . '_' . $extention;
            // Upload Image
            $path = $request->file('attachment_link')->storeAs('public/content-images/products/', $fileNameToStore);
        } else {
            $fileNameToStore = 'no-image.jpg';
        }

        $payment = new Payment;
        $payment->file = $file;
        $prePayment = $pays[$i];
        $payment->payment = str_replace(',','',$prePayment);
        $payment->paymentDate = $paymentDates[$i];
        $payment->account = $account[$i];
        $payment->attachment_link = $fileNameToStore;
        $payment->save();
    }
```

Comment: which line you are getting the error??

Comment: Can you give snippet code for your form?

Comment: @DharmaSaputra I added my form snippet too. Thank you

Comment: Hey @Sohel0415 this is the code you helped me with yesterday, If I don't add dynamic input in my form I don't get an error and also file doesn't upload to folder and I get no-image.jpg in my database. when I add dynamic input in my form same happens and I get error in this line:if ($request->hasFile($attachment[$i])) { –

Comment: `$request->hasFile('attachment_link')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this-

```
if (isset($attachment[$i])&&is_file($attachment[$i])) {
            $fileNameWithExt = $attachment[$i]->getClientOriginalName();
            // Get just filename
            $filename = pathinfo($fileNameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            // Get just ext
            $extention = $attachment[$i]->getClientOriginalExtension();
            // Filename to store
            $fileNameToStore = $filename . '_' . time() . '_' . $extention;
            // Upload Image
            $path = $attachment[$i]->storeAs('public/content-images/products/', $fileNameToStore);
        } else {
            $fileNameToStore = 'no-image.jpg';
        }
```

Comment: Perfect, it works fine but when I add the second row to my form I get 'Undefined offset: 1' in this line : if (is_file($attachment[$i])) {

Comment: it works without error but second image in database is 'no-image.jpg' and it didn't uploaded in the folder too.

Comment: you need to put a image with the same name and extension of `no-image.jpg` manually. Its indicate a string of a image name, not the actual image file

Comment: I mean when I fill the form and I have two row , two different images, only one image uploads and goes to database, second one doesnt go to the folder and database.

Comment: seems pretty odd, try to debug your code step by step, it should have worked though. Did you try changing full code?

Comment: You were right, It was my mistake. It is sorted now. thanks very much, appreciate it

Comment: @AmirNikfar may I know how did you manage to solve this issue? I am stuck here as well, please help. Thank You